# enable-oslogin failing for compute.instances.osAdminLogin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have configured enable-oslogin to TRUE on my newly created VM. When I add `compute.instances.osAdminLogin` role the IAP starts failing with message `"Server refused our key" No supported authentication methods available`. With `compute.instances.osLogin` role access is working perfectly.

```
compute.instances.get
compute.instances.getGuestAttributes
compute.instances.getSerialPortOutput
compute.instances.list
compute.instances.osLogin
compute.instances.setMetadata
compute.projects.get
compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata
```

Additional role that are assigned to the user:

```
Service Account User
Viewer
IAP-secured Tunnel User
```

Command to access VM:

```
gcloud compute ssh myserver1 --project myproject --zone us-central1-a --tunnel-through-iap
```

To test this I only change the role from `compute.instances.osLogin` to `compute.instances.osAdminLogin` and vice versa

Is this a bug or I am doing something incorrectly?

Comment: The [Compute OS Admin Login](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute.osAdminLogin) role provides "Acess to log into A compute Engine instance as an administrator user." Please also check 2nt step on [Granting OS Login IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#grant-iam-roles)"VM instance uses a service account, then each user must be configured to have the roles/iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account.".